# Create a route that matches everything that begins with something, in Codeigniter

Tags: php, regex, codeigniter, routes

I'm trying to create a route that matches anything that begins with "cms".
I tried this one:

```
$route['(^cms)'] = 'welcome';
```

It appears to match only "cms" literally. I've tried other variations - no success. The documentation of Codeigniter clearly states:

> If you prefer you can use regular expressions to define your routing rules. Any valid regular expression is allowed, as are back-references.

Any suggestions? I'll note also, that i need to be able to catch routes that have more than one slash, like "https://mysite/cms/login".

Comment: try `^cms\/.+$`

Comment: Nice, it works. The only thing that doesn't work, is when there are NO slashes after the "cms" :-) But of course i can just add another route manually. Thank you.

Comment: change it to `^cms.*$` if you dont want to check slashes

Comment: You'd want to do `^cms(\/.*)?$`. It avoids matching similar routes starting with `cms` i.e. `cmses`

Answer (score 1):

use regex: `^cms.*$`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/DsVdM7/1)

Explanation:

```
^ asserts position at start of a line
cms matches the characters cms literally (case sensitive)
.* matches any character (except for line terminators)
* Quantifier — Matches between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
$ asserts position at the end of a line
```

Answer (score 0):

Use CI route based on [doc](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/routing.html#examples)

```
$route['cms/(:any)'] = 'welcome';
```

And [get in controller](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/uri.html#class-reference)

```
https://mysite/cms/login/hello
$this->uri->segment(2); // return 'login'
$this->uri->segment(3); // return 'hello'
```